# The number of different ways to choose $k$ out of $n$ unique items

Tags: combinatorics

The number of different ways to choose $k$ out of $n$ unique items:

- Without repetition and without order-significance: $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$
- Without repetition and with order-significance: $\binom{n}{k}\times k!=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$
- With repetition and with order-significance: $n^k$
- With repetition and without order-significance: $?$

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by arranging all of your $n$ items in some canonical linear order. You then go through the line, picking some number of copies of each item. As you do this you say *"move to the next item"* $n-1$ times, and *"take one of these"* $k$ times. These instructions can be in any order, however, so there are $\binom{k+n-1}{k}$ ways to do this.

See also [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), in particular Theorem 2 on the linked page.

Comment: +1 I knew the answer, but I eally like the way you state it. ;-)

Comment: Plain and simple. Thank you very much :)